# Removing Duplicates in a linked list recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to write a recursive function that removes all adjacent duplicates in a linked list. However, my function is not working properly.

This is my attempt:

```
class Node:
    """Node in a linked list"""

    def __init__(self: 'Node', value: object = None, next: 'Node' = None) -> None:
        """Create Node self with data value and successor next."""
        self.value, self.next = value, next

def remove_dup(lnk):
    if not lnk or lnk.next:
        return lnk
    if lnk.value == lnk.next.value:
        lnk.next = lnk.next.next
    else:
        return remove_dup(lnk.next)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not` has precedence over `or`, so you need to either repeat the `not`, or put the `or` expression as an `and` in parentheses:

```
if not (lnk and lnk.next):
```

Also, when you find a duplicate, you should not stop the process, as the duplicate might occur more than twice, and there might be other duplicates as well.

So it could look like this (with a function for representing lists as string):

```
class Node:
    """Node in a linked list"""

    def __init__(self: 'Node', value: object = None, next: 'Node' = None) -> None:
        """Create Node self with data value and successor next."""
        self.value, self.next = value, next

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value) + ('->' + str(self.next) if self.next else '')

def remove_dup(lnk):
    if not (lnk and lnk.next):
        return lnk
    if lnk.value == lnk.next.value:
        lnk.next = lnk.next.next
        return remove_dup(lnk) # there might be more duplicates...
    else:
        return remove_dup(lnk.next)       

# Sample data and test
lst = Node(1, Node(3, Node(3, Node(3, Node(4, Node(4, Node(5)))))))
print (lst) # 1->3->3-3->4->4->5
remove_dup(lst)
print (lst) # 1->3->4->5
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fov6/4)

#### Some other improvements

The function `remove_dup` is a good candidate for being a method of `Node`.

And it would be nice if you could read and write a linked list as a standard list. A class method could be useful to create a linked list from a list of values, while the `__iter__` method could make your class iterable.

Then it could look like this:

```
class Node:
    """Node in a linked list"""

    def __init__(self: 'Node', value: object = None, next: 'Node' = None) -> None:
        """Create Node self with data value and successor next."""
        self.value, self.next = value, next

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.value
        if self.next:
            yield from iter(self.next) # this needs Python 3.4+

    def __repr__(self):
        return '->'.join(map(str, list(self))) # uses __iter__

    def remove_dup(self):
        if not self.next:
            return self
        if self.value == self.next.value:
            self.next = self.next.next
            return self.remove_dup() # there might be more duplicates...
        else:
            return self.next.remove_dup()

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, values):
        head = None
        for value in reversed(values):
            head = cls(value, head)
        return head

lst = Node.from_list([1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5])
print (lst) # 1->3->3->3->4->4->5
lst.remove_dup()
print (lst) # 1->3->4->5
print(list(lst)) # [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

On [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fov6/6)